# Deploy Angular JS project on httpServers as a service

Tags: angular, server

I followed up the below command to deploy my angular code for spinning up a webserver:

python -m SimpleHTTPServer 5000

I was able to access the server url but only as long as the command was running in the terminal.

I wanted to make the URLs accessible forever.
Please suggest a solution.

Comment: is this question is based on `python` or `angular` update tags accordingly please

Comment: Its angular, deploying angular code .  Python has a built-in command specifically for spinning up a webserver:

Comment: SimpleHTTPServer serves you in development.
Simply create a classic virtual server with Apache or Nginx to serve your application in production mode.